# Why do I get: Unable to determine principle end of ... error with the following code

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first

currently tweaking the model on a project I'm working on and I've hit a wall and can't seem to spot why I'm getting an error.

I have two class's

```
public class CorePage : BaseClass
{
    public CorePage()
    {
        this.PageContent = new HashSet<PageContent>();
        this.PageAliases = new HashSet<PageAlias>();
        this.isEditable = true;
    }

    public string DisplayLabel { get; set; }
    public bool isEditable { get; set; }

    public int? ParentPageId { get; set; }
    public virtual CorePage ParentPage { get; set; }

    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }        

    public int DefaultPageAliasId { get; set; }
    public virtual PageAlias DefaultPageAlias { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PageAlias> PageAliases { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PageContent> PageContent { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class PageAlias : BaseClass
{
    public PageAlias()
    {  
    }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public virtual CorePage Page { get; set; }
}
```

Relationships between the two class's are configured as follows.

```
public class CorePageConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CorePage>
{
    public CorePageConfiguration()
    {
        HasOptional(cp => cp.ParentPage).WithMany().HasForeignKey(cp => cp.ParentPageId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(p => p.DefaultPageAlias).WithRequiredDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

And

```
public class PageAliasConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PageAlias>
{
    public PageAliasConfiguration()
    {
        Property(pa => pa.Alias).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(500);
        HasRequired(pa => pa.Page).WithMany(p => p.PageAliases).HasForeignKey(pa => pa.PageId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Core.DataContext.PageAlias_Page' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.
```

And I cant seem to spot what I've missed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map `DefaultPageAlias` as a one-to-many (and not one-to-one) relationship:

```cs
HasRequired(p => p.DefaultPageAlias)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.DefaultPageAliasId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

You cannot create an one-to-one relationship with a foreign key property which is not the primary key property at the same time. EF supports only [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) to define a one-to-one relationship.

I think a shared primary key is not suited for your model because I assume `DefaultPageAlias` can be one of aliases in the `PageAliases` collection. In other words the `DefaultPageAliasId` could be 2 but also 3 or another value. This is impossible with shared primary keys because the `DefaultPageAlias` must always have the same primary key as the `CorePage`. If `CorePage` has Id=2, then `DefaultPageAlias` can only have Id=2 and no other value.

Comment: I see your point with the shared primary key association.
Regarding setting the relationship to .WithMany() it seems a little hacky but then again it guess it cant hurt as long as there is only navigation property on the CorePage side.
I'll test this and if all checks out mark as answered.
Thanks.

Comment: Your assumption that the defaultpagealias is an object in the pagealias collection is correct. Your suggested solution will build the database but doesnt perform as expected. Atleast not without some additional help. To make it work i would have to add the defaultpagealias object  to the collection when saving the corepage object which I'm not sure I can control. Perhaps there is a way to do this in a clever but not that I'm familiar with at the moment. Thanks for your help though